# Erro no build.Gradle

Tags: java, android-studio

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
>   Open File

Pessoal fui abrir um projeto, e apareceu esse erro. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor.

Comment: Teria como você detalhar mais sobre o erro ocorrido.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique sua versão do Grandle e tente atualiza-la.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' //insira um versão mais recente
    }
}
```

Tabela de relação do Android Gradle Plugin e Gradle

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Leia mais aqui: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system e sobre compatibilidade de versão aqui: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility.